# why a just defined array of array count = 1?

Tags: php

Sorry i it is duplicated,
but I don't seem to find the exact scenario I need to clarify.

So my question is why this:

```
var = array ();
echo count (var);
```

prints 0.

and this:

```
var = array (array());
echo count (var);
```

prints 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Because there is a nested array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've put an array into an array. Even if that inner array is empty, it's still **SOMETHING**.

It's like putting an empty plastic bag into another plastic bag. That outer bag now contains one item: another plastic bag.

Answer (score 1):

it is because there exist one value in the array and it does not matter whether the inner array is empty or not.

On index 0 an empty array exists which implies array is not blank so count results 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you create an empty array.

```
$var = array();
```

The contents of this array may look like this:

```
[ ]
```

There is nothing here. So, `count($var)` is zero.

But if you create a `nested` array, you would have

```
$var = array(array());
```

The contents of `$var` would now be something like this:

```
[ [] ]
```

The inner array doesn't have anything inside it. But, the outer array has an empty array inside it. And therefore, its `count` is `1`.

#### Further explanation:

Consider an array to be a plastic box.

In the first case, you have nothing inside the box, and so the `count` is `0`.

In the second case, however, you have an empty box inside the box. So, `count` is `1`.

Comment: man thanks for the further details! I accepted the first answer to be fair with the timings, but all the answers are good! Thank to you all people. Its nice to be programming alone knowing that this community exists :)

Comment: No problems. MarcB's answer is simpler and better :) And happy coding, @AlbertoPadilla!

Answer (score -1):

when you do this `var = array (array());` you have two dimensional array. if you familiar java, it seems like

```
Object var[][] = {
   {},
};
```

so, `var.length` is ", but `var[0].length` is 0